# Django duplicated url request: "home/home/'

Tags: django, django-views

I have code that works perfectly on localhost, but it is giving an error when placed on the server.

The point is that when I upload a file, it returns "base.com/home/home" (home twice = 404) instead of just "base.com/home" or the destination of the redirect.

Template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

View:

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('base-home')
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    nextr = request.GET.get('next')
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if nextr:
            return redirect(nextr)
        return redirect('base-home')
    return render(request, 'base/login.html', {'form': form})
    
@login_required    
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('base-temp', 1)
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', {'test': 'test'})
```

Url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login_page, name='base-login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_page, name='base-logout'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='base-home'),
    path('temp/<int:pk>/', views.temp, name='base-temp')
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Project settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

All other pages, media, statics are working fine. Only the post in this view.

I tried using action with `"."`, `"/home/"` and `"{% url 'base-home'%}"`, but they all give the same 404 for duplicating the home url.

I also tried to create a separate view to handle the upload, but the error became `"home/upload"` instead of `"upload"`.

I saw some similar questions in the stackoverflow, but I didn't find an answer that would work for me.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

It works if I change the template to:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And the view to:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    return redirect('base-temp', 2)
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', {'test': 'test'})
```

I'm not using django's forms.py.

That's it. Nothing else. Only the imports and a simple function view/template for base-temp.

Edit 2: Added more details about the views.

**SOLUTION:**

In case anyone else has the same problem, I leave the solution here, based on Maxwell O. Oyaro's answer.

I changed the home route to the empty path of the app urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='base-home'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_page, name='base-logout'),
    path('temp/<int:pk>/', views.temp, name='base-temp')
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then, I moved login path to the project urls.py:

```
...
from base import views as base_views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', base_views.login_page, name='login'),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your server configuration. Can you share the server you are using and the config?

Comment: I'm using namecheap. Python 3.7.3 and Django 2.2. I emphasize that other webpages and posts are functioning. Even on the same page there was another form with textarea that worked. I deleted that part of the code to delimit the problem.

Comment: Does the problem occur whenever you return a redirect? Still seems like there is something wrong with the proxy redirect settings on your web server

Comment: Other redirects work perfectly. This is the only page that has this problem and only when uploading a file. If the post is text it works on the same page.

Comment: Can you share the rest of the view/form?

Comment: @IainShelvington I edited the question to add these informations. There is nothing more than that, besides imports and a simple view/template for base-temp. It works with the textarea post (redirect to base-temp) and fails to send the file ("home/home/" = 404).

Comment: There is more to it. Where does the variable `proc` come from? Are you not handling the uploaded data at all?

Comment: First, I would like to thank you for being willing to help me. What I mean in my previous answer is that this code is enough for the problem to occur. The original code has about 600 lines in views and about 800 in the template. I wiped it up to limit the problem. I don't see much point in putting a big code here if the same error occurs with that small code. I'm going to edit the question to delete the `proc` variable, because the result is the same with a random number. In the original code I deal with the received file, but the error persists even without handling the file at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your home is defined globaly for the django project or it is for the app itself.

Putting templates globally for the project and for the app alone can be confusing. If you have a templates for the project with home and you have another home template in the app calle home, it may not give you what you expect.

Just check keenly.

Comment: Hi! The project url = `urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('', include('gabnet.urls'))] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`. Is it ok to have empty path inside both (project and app) urls.py?

Comment: That's it!! I moved the login path to the project urls.py and the home view to empty path in app urls.py. Thanks!!!